# Let $K$ be compact Hausdorff space. Is it true that any positive linear functional $\varphi\in L^{\infty}(K)$ is bounded?

Tags: functional-analysis

As it was pointed out in the title I'm interested in knowing if positive linear functionals over $L^{\infty}(K)$ are always bounded. If it is indeed true, I would appreciate any hints.

I personally don't think this holds, but the authors of the book I'm currently reading implicitly claim it does by taking the norm of positive linear functionals on $L^{\infty}(K)$. (They actually claim it for a positive functional over $C(K,\mathbb{R})$ and then somehow show that there exists an extension of that functional to $L^{\infty}(K)$ with the same norm).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose $L^{\infty} (K)$ stands for bounded real functions on $K$ with the sup norm.

If $M=\|f\|_{\infty}$ then $-M \leq f \leq M$. So $-M\phi (1) \leq \phi (f) \leq M\phi(1)$. which gives $|\phi (f)| \leq C \|f\|_{\infty}$ where $C=|\phi (1)|$. Hence $\phi $ is continuous.

Comment: How do you derive $-M\phi(1)\leq\phi(f)\leq M\phi(1)?$ Is it a consequence of positiveness?

Comment: Yes, $f \leq g$ implies $g-f \geq 0$ so $\phi (g-f) \geq 0$. By linearity we get $\phi (g) \geq \phi (f)$.  @ModestoRosado

Answer (score 1):

**The other answer appeared while I was typing on the phone (not a stupid copy, just me being slow at typing).**

You neither need compact nor Hausdorff. First we define for $f\in L^\infty$
$$ f_+:= \max\{ f, 0\}, \quad f_-:=\max\{ -f, 0\}.$$
Then we have $f=f_+-f_-$ and $\varphi(f)=\varphi(f_+)-\varphi(f_-)$. We have in general if $g\geq h\geq 0$, that $\varphi(g)=\varphi(g-h)+\varphi(h)\geq \varphi(h)\geq 0$. Now we have $\Vert f_+\Vert_\infty \geq f_+,\geq 0$ and $\Vert f_-\Vert \geq f_-\geq 0$, hence
$$ \vert \varphi(f)\vert \leq \vert \varphi(f_+)\vert + \vert \varphi(f_-)\vert \leq (\Vert f_+\Vert_\infty +\Vert f_-\Vert_\infty) \varphi(1)\leq 2\varphi(1)\Vert f\Vert_\infty.$$
Thus, the functional $\varphi$ is bounded